# How can I maintain selection in a list between page switches?

Tags: list

I have a sharepoint list with many items spread across multiple pages. In AllItems.aspx form, when I select some items, switch to the next page and then go back to the previous page I need those items to stay selected. Can someone, please, give me a clue on how to implement this?

Comment: When you say "page", do you mean "web page" or "list paging"? Regardless, the specific thing you're asking for is going to be very difficult. Someone who's a real whiz with JavaScript might be able to come up with something but it might be better to reframe the problem. Would it meet your needs if "the next page" was opened in a new tab rather than the existing one?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Aron. I mean list paging. I know it's going to be difficult and just looking for a place to start. Unfortunately, the next page has to be opened on the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's list paging, your best solution really is to just set the [item limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768269.aspx) to 1000 (or whatever number will always be greater than the number of list items you're displaying) and deal with it. If you can't accept having that large of a list on your page, you should look into writing your own paging function (probably easiest with jQuery) that'll hide list items client-side when they're not on the current page. Set the view's item limit to 1000 (or whatever) and then on page load hide items 11-1000. Then add your paging links/buttons either at the end of the table or in a content editor web part immediately below your list. Paging would show/hide appropriate items/rows, and in theory it wouldn't break SharePoint's JavaScript that handles selecting items.